# Is there any way to know if a user is getting a phonecall? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, webrtc

I'm working on a video call web application.

Every time the user is on a mobile device (iPhone or Android) and gets a phone call, the video call sound gets damage.

I've tried the `tabfocus` event but not every smartphone "unfocus" during a phone call. Some of them just show a pop up, for example.

`document.visibilityState` didn't work either.

I'm searching for a way to know about or fully block the phone call.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to listen for [BaseAudioContext.onstatechange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/onstatechange)? I believe, during the call [BaseAudioContext.state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/state) will be changed from `running` to `suspended` or `closed`.